# Passing data between UITableViewCell and UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I created master details template project in xcode 4.6 and I added custom cell with 2 textfields. I also created new class which is subclass of UITableViewCell and inside this class I created outlets for text fields. When user types something NSMutableArray is updated and this works fine. Now I am wondering how to pass this array back to MasterViewController (UITableViewController) so that I can use this data to show calculations.

I tried using tutorials for delegates between UIViewControllers but I keep getting errors. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Inside your cell subclass add a field to contain a pointer back to the controller or whatever other data anchors you need to access.  In your case you'd probably make a call back to the master VC to communicate the update.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't keep data inside the `UITableViewCell`, as it breaks the MVC.

You need to get a reference of the `UITextField` on your cell. This is how I do in a login form:

I have a custom cell subclass called `TextFieldCell`, it has an outlet called `textField`, I want that my `UITableViewController` have references to these `UITextField`s.

First I open my storyboard, set the cell class to TextFieldCell and than connect the UITextField to cell textField outlet. Than I add this to the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    (…)
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        // Sets the textField of the first cell as the loginTextField.
        self.loginTextField = tCell.textField;
    } else {
        // Sets the textField of the second cell as the passwordTextField.
        self.passwordTextField = tCell.textField;
    }
    tCell.textField.delegate = self;
    (…)
}
```

Now I can access the value of my `loginTextField` and my `passwordTextField`. I do that on the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` because that's when I'm creating the cell to add to the table view.

Comment: But how can I create outlet for the cell when I get error saying connection textField cannot have prototype object as its destination

Comment: You can't directly connect the Cell to the View Controller as the cell isn't a real object, it's a prototype to initialize objects. You need to create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass with the outlets you need and connect the `UITextField` **to the cell**.

Comment: I did that I created new class which is subclass of UITableViewCell and it works fine. However I am stuck with how to pass this data to other class like UITableViewController?

Comment: You do that where your UITableViewController have a reference to the UITableViewCell, I do that on my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, there I get variables pointing to the text fields, but you could simply get a variable pointing to the cell and than accessing data structures inside that cell. Just be aware the storing and specially processing data inside a View is usually a Bad Thing.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to create **Protocol:**

I just Give Basic Idea for how to Create **Protocol**

[Also Read This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)

```
#DetailViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol MasterDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) getButtonTitile:(NSString *)btnTitle;
@end


@interface DetailViewController : MasterViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MasterDelegate> customDelegate; 

#DetailViewController.m

if([self.customDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getButtonTitile:)])
{
          [self.customDelegate getButtonTitile:button.currentTitle];    
}

#MasterViewController.m

create obj of DetailViewController

DetailViewController *obj = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
obj.customDelegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:reportTypeVC animated:YES];

and add delegate method in MasterViewController.m for get button title.

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Custom Delegate  Method

-(void) getButtonTitile:(NSString *)btnTitle;
{
    NSLog(@"%@", btnTitle);

}
```

Comment: You are doing protocol by pushing viewController while in  my case this line of code is useless as I send data from the class which is not ViewController:

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:enterAmountVC animated:YES];